# Unrecognized selector topViewController error caused by "Use Size Classes"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I´ve seen some questions regarding the error, but in my case it´s been working for a while until I unticked the box "Use Size Classes".

Specifically, I have a segue which proceeds to a UIViewController like this:

```
UINavigationController *navCtrl = [segue destinationViewController];
myWebViewController *destController = (myWebViewController *)navCtrl.topViewController;
```

This has been working for days, until I went to the storyboard, and unticked the following box: web view controller, Interface Builder Document -> Use Size Classes. It all went wrong with the error specified in the title, the app would crash when calling that method (**[myWebViewController topViewController]: Unrecognized selector sent to instance**), and ticking the box again didn´t help, the same error would show up.

I am tempted to delete the destination view controller and do it again with a new segue, but I´m scared that this will leave something behind that the compiler won´t understand...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you inspect the storyboard. and check if the connections are as you expect them? Disabling the size classes may have changed the segue and causing the crash.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the destination had no connection, clicking that box had somehow broken my segue, the destination had all its properties to nil.